# Django: Sending e-mails asynchronous

Tags: django, email, asynchronous

I've got a Django application, which has an form to order stuff. After the form is submitted you should be forwarded to a confirmation site, while two e-mails should be send as well.

Sending an e-mail with Django is not the problem

```
send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, [order.customer.email], html_message=html_message)
```

but it seems not happening in a asynchronous way as it takes some time.

I would just like call my `send_email` method, let the sending be handled asynchronous and then proceed with forwarding.

How would I accomplish this, what kind of possibilities do I have? I am fairly new to Django/Python but I imagine creating a Thread or sth like it? Whats best practise for this case?

Comment: Standard practice is to use a task runner. Celery is probably the most popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you need to implement a task queue and worker. In my projects I use django-rq and Redis.

See the repo here: https://github.com/rq/django-rq

Then you can push the send_mail function into the queue as shown in the example:

```py
import django_rq

# process stuff here

# queue the email for sending
django_rq.enqueue(send_mail, subject, plain_message, from_email, [order.customer.email], html_message=html_message)
```

But make sure that you'll need to also have a worker in the background to actually process the items in the queue.